# Create Enumerated Function Parameter Type

Tags: sql-server-2008, functions

I want to create a function similar to DATEDIFF in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.  The first parameter in DATEDIFF is a datepart.  Can I use datepart as a parameter in my function?  If not, how do I create a parameter similar to datepart?  I don't want to make the parameter text.

For example, I would like to have a function like this: MYFUNC(datepart, timestart, timeend)

So when I call the function, it would look like this: MYFUNC(Hour, N'08:00:00', N'12:00:00')

I'm currently using a nvarchar for the datepart param so my function looks like this: MYFUNC(N'Hour', N'08:00:00', N'12:00:00')

Comment: No, you can't use a built-in like `HOUR` as a parameter - you need to pass a value that conforms to one of the data types since your parameter must be declared using a data type. Can you explain what you want to do differently from `DATEDIFF`?

Comment: I'm calculating the duration of someone's sleep based on their start and end sleep times. I'd like to mimic the datepart parameter where I can say give me the duration in hours, minutes, and seconds. Right now I'm using the nvarchar data type to distinquish between hours, minutes, and seconds.  The functions works fine, I just want to know how to create the same functionality Microsoft is using for their parameter.  It's a lot cleaner than passing a text value and it never hurts to know more :)

Comment: Right, but why do you need a *custom* function to do this? You can do this inline with conditionals without requiring a UDF or kludges to make your function *seem* like `datediff`.

Comment: True, I created a function because I'll have to reuse it multiple places within the database.  And I use the same functionality to calculate their nap duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what Microsoft does with built-ins, sorry. You will need to write your function to accept a string, for example, and evaluate it inline, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CustomDateDiff
(
  @datepart VARCHAR(32), -- does not need to be NVARCHAR
  @start    DATETIME,
  @end      DATETIME
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT CASE @datepart 
      WHEN 'HOUR'   THEN DATEDIFF(HOUR,   @start, @end) 
      WHEN 'MINUTE' THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, @end)
      WHEN 'WEEK'   THEN DATEDIFF(WEEK,   @start, @end)
      ELSE               DATEDIFF(DAY,    @start, @end)
    END);
END
GO
```

Not that you can't use a conditional *inside* `DATEDIFF` - a lot of people think you could say:

```
DATEDIFF(@datepart,
```

Or

```
DATEDIFF(CASE WHEN @datepart = 'HOUR' THEN HOUR END,
```

But neither of these will work - both yield:

> Msg 1023, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Invalid parameter 1 specified for datediff.

Comment: How would you be able to duplicate Microsoft's built-ins?  Do you have to use the CLR functionality?  Or is it exclusive to Microsoft?

Comment: You'd have to have access to SQL Server source code and make adjustments there. Any CLR functionality you write still can only accept proper SQL Server data types... never mind that `DATEDIFF` won't be able to use the variable you pass in anyway.